# setTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I've seen a few posts regarding similar issues but am a bit of a js novice so am having trouble connecting the dots in a way that makes it clear how my code needs to change, hoping someone can set me straight.

I'm trying to create a function that will reveal a specified element onMouseOver and will then hide it again onMouseOut. The area I'm struggling with here is that I need there to be a delay before the element disappears. I've never really used time delays before in a function so I'm scratching my head a bit trying to get this to work.

Through a bit of research online it seemed as though I could plug "setTimeout" straight into the onmouseout attribute on the tag and then simply include the hide function and the length of time but that doesn't seem to be working.

The markup part 1 (important parts are the <\rect> tags):

```
<svg height="400" width="580" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
<g>
<title></title>
<rect fill="#fff" height="402" id="canvas_background" width="582" x="-1" y="-1"></rect> 
<g display="none" height="100%" id="canvasGrid" overflow="visible" width="100%" x="0" y="0"> <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" height="100%" stroke-width="0" width="100%" x="0" y="0"></rect> </g> </g> <g>
<title></title>

<rect fill="#fff" height="66" id="svg_1" onmouseover="toggle_visibility('groupOne')" onmouseout="setTimeout(toggle_hidden('groupOne'), 2000)"  stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" width="126" x="74.5" y="73.299999"></rect> 

<rect fill="#fff" height="84" id="svg_2" onmouseover="toggle_visibility('groupTwo')" onmouseout="setTimeout(toggle_hidden('groupTwo'), 2000)" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" width="124" x="76.5" y="173.299999"></rect> 

<rect fill="#fff" height="42" id="svg_3" onmouseover="toggle_visibility('groupThree')" onmouseout="setTimeout(toggle_hidden('groupThree'), 2000)" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" width="68" x="240.5" y="43.299999"></rect>

<rect fill="#fff" height="48" id="svg_4" onmouseover="toggle_visibility('groupFour')" onmouseout="setTimeout(toggle_hidden('groupFour'), 2000)" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" width="92" x="348.5" y="41.299999"></rect> 

<rect fill="#fff" height="138" id="svg_5" onmouseover="toggle_visibility('groupFive')" onmouseout="setTimeout(toggle_hidden('groupFive'), 2000)" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" width="72" x="242.5" y="113.299999"></rect>

<rect fill="#fff" height="66" id="svg_6" onmouseover="toggle_visibility('groupSix')" onmouseout="setTimeout(toggle_hidden('groupSix'), 2000)" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" width="84" x="372.5" y="193.299999"></rect> </g> 
</svg>
```

The markup part 2 (items that are being hidden or shown):

```
<ul class="hide" id="groupOne">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="hide" id="groupTwo">
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <li>List item 5</li>
    <li>List item 6</li>
</ul>

<ul class="hide" id="groupThree">
    <li>List item 7</li>
    <li>List item 8</li>
    <li>List item 9</li>
</ul>

<ul class="hide" id="groupFour">
    <li>List item 10</li>
    <li>List item 11</li>
    <li>List item 12</li>
</ul>

<ul class="hide" id="groupFive">
    <li>List item 13</li>
    <li>List item 14</li>
    <li>List item 15</li>
</ul>

<ul class="hide" id="groupSix">
    <li>List item 16</li>
    <li>List item 17</li>
    <li>List item 18</li>
</ul>
```

The js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.classList.contains('hide')) {
            e.classList.add('show');
            e.classList.remove('hide');
        } else {
            e.classList.add('hide');
        }

    }

    function toggle_hidden(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.classList.contains('show')) {
            e.classList.add('hide');
        }            
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any constructive advice on how I should be tackling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing `toggle_hidden` to `setTimeout` to be called in 2 seconds, but calling it immediately.

```
onmouseout="setTimeout(function(){ toggle_hidden('groupOne'); }, 2000)"
```

Comment: Dude that was quick, thanks! It seems to have fixed the issue, I'll be marking this as the answer once the ten minutes lets up and I'm able.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function `toggle_hidden` immediately, instead of passing the reference.

You could use `bind` to bind the argument to it. So change:

```
toggle_hidden('groupTwo')
```

to:

```
toggle_hidden.bind(null, 'groupTwo')
```

...etc.